# How to save an Image?

Tags: javafx, filechooser

I am using `javafx.stage.FileChooser` to give the user ability to browse system and save the image he/she wants. this is my code:

```
    Stage fileChooserStage = new Stage();
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Select an Image");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add( new ExtensionFilter("Image Files", "*.png", "*.jpg", "*.gif"));
    File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(fileChooserStage);
```

Now i need to save the image that the user chooses in a package(folder which is in the same 
directory as my packages),How should i do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java.awt.Image, you can use the SwingFXUtils.toFXImage() which will return a Buffered Image. This has a reverse option as well for converting to an fx image.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `FileWriter` that wraps `file`:

```
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file))
{
    out.write(result);
}
```

Where `result` represents a byte array that represents your Image. If you are using a `java.awt.Image`, you can use methods from the `ImageIO` class. If you are using a `javafx.scene.image.Image`, then see [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2450090?tstart=0).